# Add event for PictureBox mouse down

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I want to make this event to work:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //code
}
```

I know I have to add an event for this to work but I wasn't able to find the syntax anywhere. How can I add this event?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to assign event handler to the event, usually in the form's constructor:

```
class MyForm 
{ 
    PictureBox pictureBox1;

    public MyForm()
    {
        ...
        InitializeComponent(); 
        ...
        pictureBox1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(pictureBox1_MouseDown);
        ... 
    }
}
```

If you added your control through Form Designer in Visual Studio, it will automatically generate `InitializeComponent()` method which creates controls (calls their constructors) so make sure you're accessing controls after the call to `InitializeComponent()`.

You can also assign event handler to the event through Form Designer: select control, right click it, select *Properties*, click on flash icon (*Events*), find desired event (`MouseDown`) and double click it - event handler method will be assigned to that event (you can check the code in `InitializeComponent()`). Now you just have to write the code in the body of the event handler.

Comment: Should be placed in the `OnLoad` method or at the end of constructor.

Comment: Very interesting what you said about generating the events automatically. I just came from VB.NET and thought that C# did not had such feature. Thank you.