# How to find out did mouse hover pictureBox created in code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, object

I need to know did mouse hovered my picturebox. If i add it from Toolbox i will just add event but how to do it from code. I tried this:

```
if(Cursor.Position == myObject.Location)
{
   //do something...
}
```

But it does not work, can anyone give me solution to this problem?

Comment: You can also add event via code.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya How?

Comment: If you are adding mousehover event or mousemove event when you add it from code, the same events you need to add from code. And create a method `MouseMovedOverPictureBox`  and write your logic there and following code would attach the event handler to the dynamic picutrebox `pictureBox1.MouseMove += MouseMovedOverPictureBox`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580560/add-event-for-picturebox-mouse-down

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to Idan's answer you can also use a [lambda](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) expression:

```
PictureBox pBox = new PictureBox() { SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom };
pBox.MouseHover += (ss, ee) =>
{
    // your code here
    // .. 
};
```

Note that I changed the names of `sender` and `e` to something else (your choice) because often this code is in an event itself. If you put it into a function, there is no need to change the names..

Also noteworthy: Any variables defined in the same [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions#variable-scope-in-lambda-expressions) as the code above will stay available to the code! This can be an advantage of using a lambda..

---

But, of course you can also use the code from your question, if you do it right:

```
if(myobject.ClientRectangle.Contains(myobject.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition)))
{
   //do something...
};
```

Note

- I use the`Rectangle.Contains`function
- I convert the screen coordinates of `Control.MousePosition` to those relative to the control..

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify which technology you are using. Supposing it is WinForms, 
you need to add an event handler to the control's MouseHover event, something like:

```
this.pictureBox.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox_MouseHover);
```

then, do what you want inside "pictureBox_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)" function.